# for the HEX puzzle game, the objects spawn on top of each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a HEX puzzle game.But the problem is that the objects that spawn are overlapping because I'm random and I want to delete the objects that overlap and sort them as in the picture, but I couldn't.I'm using the unity gaming engine.You can help in this regard?

```
void Update()
{
        StartCoroutine(Create());

}



IEnumerator Create()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(start_standby);
    while (true)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (randHexagon <= 5)
            {
                Vector3 vec = new Vector3(Random.Range(-randomPos.x, randomPos.x), Random.Range(-randomPos.y, randomPos.y), 0);
                Instantiate(spawnObject[randHexagon], vec, Quaternion.identity);

            }


                yield return new WaitForSeconds(create_wait);


        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(loop_wait);
        if (finishGame)
        {
            returnStart = true;
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

}

the result is that Hexagon, which is composed of sequential and random colors, is supposed to occur on the screen, but the Hexagon, which is formed, comes in a row and does not come in a straight line.

Comment: Well, you can start with eliminating the `StartCoroutine(Create());` in the `Update` method., since it spawns a coroutine on EACH FRAME.

Comment: Ok but how can I sort the hexagons like this?

Comment: https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiP8cPL2qnhAhVRiqQKHTBeAY0QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fanswers.unity.com%2Fquestions%2F960064%2Fhexagon-grid-distance.html&psig=AOvVaw1YvaApFKQuQnpROUC4tn0Z&ust=1554029844103734

Answer (score 1):

Start with placing your Coroutine call in a method that gets called once like in a "Start" if you do not wish to run this coroutine every frame.

If you want to place the Hexagons in a Grid Based game the best idea will be to use a data structure to store the hexagons and keep spawning them like you do it in an array one after another this will prevent the overlap

If you want to spawn Hexagons randomly you can easily stop overlapping by using a Physics.Overlap methods which basically checks if there is something overlapping and with that you can go ahead.